# JS: adding multiples rules within replace method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was using the replace method with the following regex to strip periods at the end of a string: `replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");` .  Now I want to change this to meet the following requirements:

- can't end with a period,
- can't contain only spaces
- can't contain the following characters: \ / * ? " | : < >

Is there a way to incorporate the other 2 rules with my rule that is already stripping the period?

Comment: You mean like "remove the period in the end"?

Comment: Or do you need to TEST string for of it conforms the rule?

Comment: Not clear. Example `replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");` removes a period and everything after it. E.g. if you have two sentences in a string, first one with period, second one with question, it will remove the second sentence.

Can you add a few input examples with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s
   .replaceAll(/\s/g, '')
   .replaceAll(/[\\/*?"|:<>]/g, '')
   .replace(/\.+$/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this combined regex, which will match all of the things you would like to exclude: `/\.+$|\\|\/|\*|\?|\"|\||\:|\<|\>|^\s+$/g`.

To remove invalid characters from a string, use:

```js
s = s.replace(/\.+$|\\|\/|\*|\?|\"|\||\:|\<|\>|^\s+$/g, '')
if (!s) {
  // The string is entirely whitespace
}
```

If you just want to check the existence of invalid characters, use:

```js
if (/\.+$|\\|\/|\*|\?|\"|\||\:|\<|\>|^\s+$/g.exec(s)) {
  // The string is invalid
} else {
  // The string is valid
}
```